# Do CSS transition after a jquery fadeOut

Tags: jquery, css

On this https://jsfiddle.net/8oguLv0d/ there are red and green boxes.
If one clicks the 'click me' button, then the red boxed fade out with the ***fadeOut*** method from jQuery and the green boxes jump to their new position.

I want that the green boxes move smoothly to their new position. How can I achieve this? I tried to supply them with the CSS transition option

```
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
```

but then the jQuery fadeOut method doesn't work anymore.

---

Here is the ***jsfiddle*** code:

HTML

```
<div id="clickme">Click me</div>
<ul>
    <li><div class='a'></div></li>
    <li><div class='a'></div></li>
    <li><div class='a'></div></li>
    <li><div class='b'></div></li>
    <li><div class='a'></div></li>
    <li><div class='a'></div></li>
    <li><div class='b'></div></li>
    <li><div class='a'></div></li>
    <li><div class='a'></div></li>
    <li><div class='a'></div></li>
    <li><div class='b'></div></li>
    <li><div class='a'></div></li>
    <li><div class='b'></div></li>
</ul>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#clickme").click(function(){
    $('.a').fadeOut(1000);
                });
   });
```

CSS

```
  li{
        list-style-type: none;

        float: left;
    }

    li div{
        margin: 20px;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
    }

    li div.a{
        background-color: red;
    }

    li div.b{
        background-color: green;
    }

    #clickme{
      background-color: blue;
      text-align: center;
      color: #FFF;
      cursor: pointer;
     }
    }
```

Comment: Add transition to LIs.

Comment: @Jai do you mean like this https://jsfiddle.net/fn092eo5/? Because that doesnt work, right?

Comment: You're not actually "changing" the positional coordinates of the green boxes, so transition has no effect. If they were positioned with `top`, `left`, `right` or `bottom` values, then you could change those and see the transition.

Comment: If you're absolutely set on this effect I'd look at something like `isotope masonry` - it works by setting items with absolute position and then changing their position when the DOM changes - this is much easier to animate than falling into gaps as effectively there's nothing to animate

Answer (score 3):

You can add class with transition to red elements after fadeOut.

```
  $("#clickme").click(function(){
    $('.a').fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $('.a').addClass('hide');
    });
  });
```

and set transition to this elements:

```
li div.a.hide{
      -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 1s ease-in-out;

      opacity: 0;
      display: block !important;
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      height: 0;

    }
```

You still will have problems with floating.
You should brake this list to for example 4 li elements with floating and inside them insert your boxes. Then whole animation should be fine.

Here is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x6th74xr/

**Change layout to 4 li elements**

```
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class='a'></div>
        <div class='a'></div>
        <div class='b'></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class='a'></div>
        <div class='b'></div>
        <div class='a'></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class='b'></div>
        <div class='a'></div>
        <div class='a'></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class='a'></div>
        <div class='a'></div>
        <div class='a'></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

and fiddle for this change: https://jsfiddle.net/htaexnn6/

Answer (score 0):

You can try using jQuery and set a delay superior the the fadeOut duration to your .b class:

```
    $("#clickme").click(function(){
        $('.a').fadeOut();
        $('.b').delay(1000).fadeIn();
    });
```

To achieve this, you need the fadeOut() to be done before calling the next transition (ie *fadeIn()* the .b class).

See it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/liototo/8oguLv0d/1/

Comment: Thank you. It is a nice animation, but I want to create a transition animation.

Answer (score 0):

**JQuery** - just toggle Class

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#clickme").click(function(){
  $('div').toggleClass('a');
  });
});
```

**CSS** - check between "With 'a' Class" and "Without 'a' Class"

```
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
}

li div {
  margin: 20px 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

li div.a {
  opacity: 1.0;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 100px;
}

li div.b {
  opacity: 1.0;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

#clickme {
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```